# Message at the end of the game

Tags: python

I managed to write simple Pong game that last till someone gets to 5. But, I can't get message at the end "The winner is player1/player2". Window just closes and I am again in Main Menu.

Here Game class of that Pong game:

```
import pygame
from random import randint
from stick import Stick
from loptica import Loptica
from rezultati import Rezultati
import sqlite3

pygame.init()

class Igra:
    def __init__(self, duzinaProzora, sirinaProzora, brIgraca, igrac1, igrac2, igra):
        def resetLoptice():
            loptica.rect.x = duzinaProzora/2
            loptica.rect.y = sirinaProzora/2
            loptica.brzina = [4*randint(-1,1),4*randint(-1,1)]
            while loptica.brzina[0] == 0:
                loptica.brzina = [4*randint(-1,1),4*randint(-1,1)]
        self.duzinaProzora = duzinaProzora
        self.sirinaProzora = sirinaProzora
        self.brIgraca = brIgraca
        self.igrac1 = igrac1
        self.igrac2 = igrac2
        self.igra = igra

        prozor = pygame.display.set_mode((self.duzinaProzora, self.sirinaProzora))
        pygame.display.set_caption("VDPong")
        pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('ball.jpg'))

        stick1 = Stick ((255,255,0),10,100)
        stick1.rect.x = 25
        stick1.rect.y = sirinaProzora / 2 - 50

        stick2 = Stick ((255,255,0),10,100)
        stick2.rect.x = duzinaProzora - 35
        stick2.rect.y = sirinaProzora / 2 - 200
        
        loptica = Loptica((0,0,0),10,10)
        loptica.rect.x = duzinaProzora/2
        loptica.rect.y = sirinaProzora/2

        lista_spriteova = pygame.sprite.Group()
        lista_spriteova.add(stick1)
        lista_spriteova.add(stick2)
        lista_spriteova.add(loptica)

        rezultat = ""
        
        vrijeme = pygame.time.Clock()

        bodoviA = 0
        bodoviB = 0

        while self.igra:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.igra = False
            
            kontrole = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if self.brIgraca == 2:
                if kontrole[pygame.K_w]:
                    stick1.moveUp(5)
                if kontrole[pygame.K_s]:
                    stick1.moveDown(5,sirinaProzora)
            else:
                if loptica.rect.y <= stick1.rect.y + 50:
                    stick1.moveUp(4)
                if loptica.rect.y >= stick2.rect.y + 50:
                    stick1.moveDown(4,sirinaProzora)
                igrac1 = "COM"
            if kontrole[pygame.K_UP]:
                stick2.moveUp(5)
            if kontrole[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                stick2.moveDown(5,sirinaProzora)
            
            lista_spriteova.update()

            if loptica.rect.x >= duzinaProzora - 10:
                bodoviA +=1
                resetLoptice()
            if loptica.rect.x <= 0:
                bodoviB +=1
                resetLoptice()
            if loptica.rect.y >= sirinaProzora - 10:
                loptica.brzina[1] = -loptica.brzina[1]
            if loptica.rect.y<=0:
                loptica.brzina[1] = -loptica.brzina[1]
            
            if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(loptica, stick1) or pygame.sprite.collide_mask(loptica, stick2):
                loptica.bounce()
                loptica.brzina[0] *= 1.1
                if loptica.brzina[0] >= 9:
                    loptica.brzina[0] == 9
            
            prozor.fill((0,0,255))

            pygame.draw.line(prozor, (255,255,0) , [duzinaProzora/2, 0], [duzinaProzora/2, sirinaProzora], 5)

            lista_spriteova.draw(prozor)

            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
            text = font.render(str(bodoviA), 1, (255,255,0))
            prozor.blit(text, (duzinaProzora/2-60,255))
            text = font.render(str(bodoviB), 1, (255,255,0))
            prozor.blit(text, (duzinaProzora - duzinaProzora/2 + 40,255))
            text = font.render(str(igrac1), 1, (255,255,0))
            prozor.blit(text, (duzinaProzora/4,20))
            text = font.render(str(igrac2), 1, (255,255,0))
            prozor.blit(text, (duzinaProzora - duzinaProzora/4-40,20))

            pygame.display.flip()

            vrijeme.tick(60)


            if bodoviA == 5 or bodoviB == 5:
                rezultat = str(bodoviA) + ":" + str(bodoviB)
                break
        
        rez = Rezultati(igrac1, igrac2, rezultat)
        
        rez.bazaRezultata(igrac1,igrac2,rezultat)
'''
        with sqlite3.connect("Baza.db") as conn:
            interface = conn.cursor()

        upis = f"INSERT INTO Rezultati(Igrac1,Igrac2,Rezultat) VALUES ('{self.igrac1}','{self.igrac2}','{rezultat}');"
        interface.execute(upis)
'''

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a specific line of code that can make text in the pygame window, as shown below.

```
text = font.render('GeeksForGeeks', True, green, blue)
```

If you want a full documented resource try

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-display-text-to-pygame-window/